# Can't launch OpenStack Horizon Dashboard IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key'

Tags: mod-wsgi, openstack, openstack-horizon

I installed OpenStack on ubuntu 16.04 vagrant box, all works well except the dashboard, when I open it I am getting the below error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=6601): Target WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=6601): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/settings.py", line 335, in <module>
    from local.local_settings import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py", line 132, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = secret_key.generate_or_read_from_file('/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key')
  File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/horizon/utils/secret_key.py", line 68, in generate_or_read_from_file
    key = read_from_file(key_file)
  File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/horizon/utils/secret_key.py", line 50, in read_from_file
    with open(key_file, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key'
```

I understand that the key is generated by Apache, below the permissions for the key.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/var/lib/openstack-dashboard$ ls -ltrh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4.0K Feb 22 19:40 secret-key
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        0 Mar  6 08:19 _var_lib_openstack-dashboard_secret_key.lock
-rw-------  1 root     root       64 Mar  6 08:19 secret_key
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data 4.0K Mar  6 10:06 static
```

I installed Dashboard by following the [installation guide](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/install-guide-ubuntu/horizon.html).

Comment: The Python code is run as the Apache user. That file is owned by root and not accessible to other users.

Comment: How this file is generated? Apache is running with root user.

`vagrant@vagrant:~$ ps -ef |grep apache2
root      3782     1  0 20:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28787  3782  0 21:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28788  3782  0 21:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`

Comment: Only the Apache parent process runs as root. All processes which handle requests drop privileges and run as the www-data process. Something must have run as root to create that file in the first place and now the www-data processes cannot access it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton correct, issue solved by chown
`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/lib/openstack-dashboard/secret_key`

Answer (score 2):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data  secret-key
```

Then, it's OK!

```
root@controller:/var/lib/openstack-dashboard# ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 May  9 13:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 51 root     root     4096 May  9 13:29 ../
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data   64 May  9 13:29 secret_key
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Apr  2 18:44 secret-key/
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data 4096 May  9 13:29 static/
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        0 May  9 13:29 _var_lib_openstack-dashboard_secret_key.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

checking the openStack-dashboard.conf located in

/etc/apache2/conf-available/openStack-dashboard.conf

The user to which permission had to be granted was mentioned as:

WSGIDaemonProcess horizon user=horizon group=horizon processes=3 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}

So, changing the permission to user -> horizon worked for me
sudo chown horizon /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_dashboard/local/.secret_key_store

sudo chmod 0600 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_dashboard/local/.secret_key_store